# problems subclassing a tabbar in XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I am looking to make a raised centre tab bar and have seen the examples but when subclassing I can't get it to work? I must be missing some thing somewhere!?!?! I am getting errors in the code **[self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Kitchens"],** (no visible @interface for 'HomeViewController' declares the selector 'viewControllerWithTabTitle;') and **[self addCenterButtonWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reversedlogo.png"]];** (no visible @interface for 'HomeViewController' declares the selector 'addCentreButtonWithImage;')

please can someone point out where I am going wrong.

Thank you

Subclass is the base view controller:

.m

```
@implementation BaseViewController

// Create a view controller and setup it's tab bar item with a title and image
-(UIViewController*) viewControllerWithTabTitle:(NSString*) title image:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:image tag:0];
    return viewController;
}

// Create a custom UIButton and add it to the center of our tab bar
-(void) addCenterButtonWithImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage highlightImage:(UIImage*)highlightImage
{
    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    if (heightDifference < 0)
        button.center = self.tabBar.center;
    else
    {
        CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
        center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
        button.center = center;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

.h

```
@interface BaseViewController : UITabBarController
{
}

// Create a view controller and setup it's tab bar item with a title and image
-(UIViewController*) viewControllerWithTabTitle:(NSString*)title image:(UIImage*)image;

// Create a custom UIButton and add it to the center of our tab bar
-(void) addCenterButtonWithImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage highlightImage:(UIImage*)highlightImage;

@end
```

then my home view is:

.m

```
@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createStoneData];

    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            **[self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Kitchens"],** (no visible @interface for 'HomeViewController' declares the selector 'viewControllerWithTabTitle;')
                            [self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Studies"],
                            [self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Libraries"],
                            [self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"" image:nil],
                            [self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Dressing Rooms"],
                            [self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Bathrooms"],
                            [self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Contact Us"],

}

-(void)willAppearIn:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
    {
        **[self addCenterButtonWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reversedlogo.png"]];** (no visible @interface for 'HomeViewController' declares the selector 'addCentreButtonWithImage;')
    }




- (void)createStoneData {

    self.homeImages = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self.homeImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Biddlesdon Wardrobes", @"name",
                                @"_NP19981-Edit.jpg", @"image", nil]];
    [self.homeImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                    initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"South Stoke Bathroom", @"name",
                                    @"_NP17744.jpg", @"image", nil]];

    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.homeImages.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *homeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    homeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.homeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_startingIndexPath) {
        NSInteger currentIndex = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - scrollView.bounds.size.width / 1) / scrollView.bounds.size.width) + 1;
        if (currentIndex < [self.homeImages count]) {
            self.title = self.homeImages[currentIndex][@"name"];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

.h

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : BaseViewController {}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *homeImages;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *startingIndexPath;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

- (void)createStoneData;


@end
```

Comment: and what is your problem ?

Comment: see edit about errors

Comment: if you copy codes from the internet you should make sure that they are complete and you shouldn't present them as yours.

Answer (score 1):

It's totally normal because you don't create specified methods.

Let's see in your `BaseViewController.h`, you've two methods which are

```
-(void) addCenterButtonWithImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage highlightImage:(UIImage*)highlightImage

-(UIViewController*) viewControllerWithTabTitle:(NSString*) title image:(UIImage*)image
```

you see that the declared methods takes two parameters, but you call them with one parameter.
Like,

```
[self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Kitchens"]
```

which expects the second parameter as an **UIImage**.

As parameters are a part of method names, you got **no visible interface** error. Because you don't have any method in your base class named :

```
 -(UIViewController*) viewControllerWithTabTitle:(NSString*) title;
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, have amended that but the addCenterButtonWithImage error is also confusing me as i do have this?

Comment: you have to do the same thing to addCenterButtonWithImage as well, because you call it with one parameter.

Comment: agh this just hadn't updated but cleared when I tried to run, It has crashed with the breakpoint being the } at the end of the  viewControllerWithTabTitle section. I'm using storyboards, do I need to remove the tab bar at all? sorry completely new to this!